# Как установить высоту для divider в теме приложения?

Tags: android

Необходимо в Navigation Drawer использовать разделители высотой 0.5 dp и определенного цвета.

Установить цвет получилось(атрибут listDivider), но не получается найти атрибут темы который отвечает за высоту.

Пробовал добавить в тему dividerHeight, но он ничего не поменял.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.Dragonfly" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/white</item>
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Button.Action</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Button.Action</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@color/geyser</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Попробовал вместо NavigationView добавить фрагмент - он выводится на экран а не в меню.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Вообще, если хочется сильно кастомизировать, то проще убрать NavigationView и заменить его RecyclerView. Ну или вообще отдельным фрагментом с любой разметкой. Также можете попробовать вот отсюда решение: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/663. Например, переопределить разметку разделителя.

Comment: Так если же добавить фрагмент, то он появится на экране, а не в боковом меню. Нужно из navigationView как то его привязать?

Comment: Смотря как и куда добавлять. Добавьте в размеку прямо вместо навигатьон вью. Или вместо оного добавьте контейнер и фрагмент программно добавляйте. Все будет работать

Comment: Добавил в разметку - фрагмент добавился на экран, а не боковое меню. [screenshot](https://umbrellait.rapira.com/MZYwPE)

Comment: А как добавили? Покажите разметку. И скриншот посмотреть не могу - не хожу по незнакомым ссылкам от незнакомых людей. Добавьте лучше картинку картинкой прямо в вопрос через правку оного

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: Вы забыли `android:layout_gravity="start"`прописать.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не знал что так можно)